# Use a HTML form to create new list items

Tags: list, javascript, form, aspx

I've created a HTML form webpart with some inputs. I want to insert the data contained by the inputs into a Sharepoint List on submit.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use CSOM-JS.

Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767461/sharepoint-form-webpart-with-javascript on how your html form should look like and this on how to do basic JS operations in SharePoint 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx (SharePoint 2010: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for marking as an answer. I appreciate when people find stuff helpful and let others know that it's correct.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for your answer, it is very useful